# Updating imageView from Task thread

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx-8

I wrote a ray tracer rendering application and now I'm trying to connect it to the GUI. I want to achieve the effect of pixel by pixel process rendering from white canvas to the result. Specifically, when my tracing application computes the color of some pixel I want it immideately written to the image. Instead of that GUI gets freezed while rendering and shows only final result. Then I decided to fix it with rendering process running in background thread. After reading some documentation I've found out that in order to dynamically update GUI one shoud use Tasks and Platform.runLater method. That is the code related to my problem:
In RenderWindowController i have ImageView connected to XML form

```
@FXML
private volatile ImageView imageView;
```

After creating a scene this code runs rendering process

```
Task<Void> task = new Task<Void>() {
        @Override
        protected Void call() throws Exception {
            world.getCamera().renderScene(world);
            return null;
        }
    };
```

Method renderScene loops over rows and columns of the image and computes color for each pixel

```
...
WritableImage img = ...
PixelWriter pixelWriter = img.getPixelWriter();
for rows {
    for columns {
...
pixelColor = tracer.traceRay();
pixelWriter.setColor(column, row, pixelColor);
Platform.runLater(() ->  *reference to my ImageView*.setImage(image));
    } 
}
```

This code does the same thing as if i were not using threads.
I'm new to threads and JavaFX. Can anyone point out what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score -3):

Maybe this link can be useful to read. It's about concurrency like in Swing.
The link contains some code examples.

https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/threads/jfxpub-threads.htm

e.g.

```
   import javafx.concurrent.Task;

    Task<Integer> task = new Task<Integer>() {
     @Override protected Integer call() throws Exception {
     int iterations;
     for (iterations = 0; iterations < 100000; iterations++) {
        if (isCancelled()) {
           break;
        }
        System.out.println("Iteration " + iterations);
     }
     return iterations;
    }
   };
```